# Blender 2.8 and Animation Nodes build from Chris Prenninger

Tags: animation-nodes

As Blender 2.8 has a new build everyday, is the Animation Nodes build from Chris Prenninger (made on May 5) still valid?
It does not work for me :(

Comment: Please don't ask the same question many times. If you are not getting answers, or the answers don’t help, then edit your original post with more information and detailing what you have tried that is not working. Read: [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: Noted. Thanks for your comment. I am new on Blender (and Animation Nodes). It was my first question on this web site. I am going to update my question with what I have tried and what was not working.